# Persistence using Postgres

Tags: elsa-workflows

I want to use Postgres for Persistence. I have added the following code.

```
services
.AddElsa(elsa => elsa
.UseEntityFrameworkPersistence(p => p.UsePostgreSql(connectionstring)))
```

I get following exception. DB is created and 'Elsa' schema is created but it has only

```
__EFMigrationsHistory" table with no rows.
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.Builders.OperationBuilder`1<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.CreateIndexOperation>
```

---

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationBuilder.CreateIndex(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean, System.String)'.
```

I am using 2.13.0 version of

```
Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.PostgreSql.
```

Am I missing anything ? Any references or sample project using Postgres?